# How to route in /web directory from localhost:8000 in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working with a local symfony proyect in localhost:8000 turning on the server with "php bin\console server:run". Working there, how can i route a file that i have in web directory? Working in xampp server i do this way: localhost/my_project/web/filename.jpg

Comment: Something strange happens with some images. When I type the path in the browser (ex. localhost:8000/folder/image.jpg) instead of being displayed in the window the file is downloaded. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in web directory it is already available. You can use `asset('filename.jpg')`.

It will be available as

https://localhost:8000/filename.jpg

Comment: first run the assets install command. `bin/console assets:install --symlink`

Comment: @MertÖksüz. .  But if file is already in web directory, there is no need of it. However you can consider `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` to clear routing cache

Comment: yes, i said for generally. may he moved that file by hand.